# GCM Notification and getStringExtra();

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

For a few days I am facing a problem I can not solve , I have an application that receives notification via the GCM until all is well and I well my message notification. But the problem is when I click on my notification and its acitivity in question opens the getStringExtra () function often sends me the same thing as the previous notification when my notification message to be changing .

To better understand the treatment here when the notification arrives on the service :

```
private void sendNotification(String greetMsg) {
        String sMsg = "";
        String sNotifMsg = "";
        int iTypeNotif=0;
        Date now = new Date();
        notifyID = now.getTime();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotifAcitivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("greetjson", greetMsg); // HERE I HAVE GIVE THE MESSAGE
        resultIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(notifyID));
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int) notifyID,
                resultIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(greetMsg);
            sMsg = jsonObj.getString("msg");
            Log.v(Constantes.TAG, "MESSAGE = "+sMsg);

            // Récuperer le type de notfif
            Log.v(Constantes.TAG, ProcedureGlobale.getParams("TYPE_NOTIF",sMsg)); // HERE THE MESSAGE CHANGE WELL
            iTypeNotif = Integer.parseInt(ProcedureGlobale.getParams("TYPE_NOTIF",sMsg));

            switch (iTypeNotif){
                case Constantes.TYPE_MSG:
                    sNotifMsg = "Vous avez une message d'utilisateur.";
                    break;
                case Constantes.TYPE_TEMPS:
                    sNotifMsg = "Un de vos compte arrive à terme.";
                    break;
                case Constantes.TYPE_AMENDE:
                    sNotifMsg = "Vous avez une amende.";
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText(sNotifMsg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
        int defaults = 0;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        defaults = defaults | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
        // Set the content for Notification
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(sNotifMsg);
        // Set autocancel
        mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Post a notification
        mNotificationManager.notify((int)notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
```

So as I said here the message of my change notification well in the log.v and is well pass into PutString ();

But then in my Activity under the getStringExtra () sometimes returns me an old notification message:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notif_acitivity);
    String sRetour = null;
    String json = getIntent().getStringExtra("greetjson");
    Log.v(Constantes.TAG, "Json = " + json);
    sRetour = Constantes.PARAM_TYPE_ECHAN + "NOTIF;";
```

Do you have an idea, I'm sure I a different id for each notification. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag to your `PendingIntent.getActivity()` call instead of 0.

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) states, if the PendingIntent already exists (and a new notification was selected), keep it but replace the `extras` content.

Lastly, you don't need to call `setAction` on your intent since it is an explicit intent. Moreover, the value you specify for it doesn't really point to anything relevant.

Comment: Sorry but the problem persists.